# Connecting to remote MySQL server using PHP7.3 and proxy

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, proxy

I am attempting to connect to a remote MySQL server from my local machine virtualhost using Proxifier Proxy (Socks5).

I am connect is working on Navicat, And using `mysql -h 192.168.0.44 -u my_user -p -P port` cmd is working too. Then I attempting using the following code:

```php
$link = mysqli_connect('192.168.0.44', 'my_user', 'my_pwd', 'db_name', 'port');
if (!$link) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
} else {
    echo 'Connected successfully';
}
exit();
```

My problem is that I am unable to connect locally using PHP, receiving the error:

> mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Operation timed out

It's connecting success on Navicat For Mysql And commands:
[image: It's connecting success on Navicat For Mysql And commands]

Comment: Are you running the PHP code from the same IP as the command line or Navicat? It might be a config issue on the MySQL side.

Comment: yes，it's same IP.

Comment: And my colleague it's working using the same PHP code on his computer.

Comment: Is he connecting using Proxifier Proxy also? By default, PHP expects MySQL connection can be established using port 3306.

Comment: Yes,seem this picture：[link]https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRDIx.png

Comment: Our company can't  connecting the online databases using public ip.

Comment: Ok, there you go!